# Movie with scientists running across some kind of desert being chased by a silver tripod

Tags: story-identification, movie

I need help remembering the name of a movie that I want to say showed up on the Syfy channel ages ago, had to be early 2000s. I don't remember it being anywhere besides the Syfy channel (when it was called that) so I'm betting it was low budget.

I don't remember much other than it had scientists running across some kind of desert being chased by a silver tripod that was smaller than the war of the worlds tripod. I vaguely remember it could vaporize people in a similar fashion as well but I think this was some military weapon or AI gone rogue.

Comment: do you remember anything else about the movie? Was it 'modern' (2000+) production values, or something from say, like the 70's / 80s's etc...

Comment: May be Amee robot from the Red Planet ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y75hrsA7jyw

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi - That film always makes me laugh, especially given that the acme of rover technology in 2021 could be knocked over by a stiff breeze or a misplaced grain of sand.

Comment: Did the tripod look anything like the one from ["The Tripods"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tripods_(TV_series))? (see: https://spdk1.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/tripods-episode-1-capping-ceremony-tripod.png and https://airwolfthemes.com/images/about/other-soundtracks/tripods_Pics_02.jpg and https://spdk1.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/tripods-episode-2-tripod.png). The desert setting doesn't match, though.

Comment: Tripod in Scary Movie 4 - too big? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2YHyEC_xG5A